# How to add a single HUGO page independent of theme and also add reference to SCSS?

Tags: hugo

I want to add a custom HTML page completely independent of the theme but at the same time want to reference the SCSS file for style.

What I have tried till now:

As per https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/scss-sass/ added below in HTML, not in the layout file but the actual content HTML file.

```
{{ $sass := resources.Get "sass/main.scss" }} 
{{ $style := $sass | resources.ToCSS }}
```

This output the above code without parsing.

Answer (score 0):

For that custom page, you can create a new directory with the name of the page in the layouts folder and add a `single.html` file inside it. Also add the sass implementation in that `single.html` file. The folder structure will be like this:

```
Hugo Project
├── content
├── layouts
├── ├── _default
├── ├── partial
│   └── custom_dir(the url outside of the theme)
│      └── single.html
├── static
├── themes
└──config.toml
```

Sass implementation:

```
{{ $sass := resources.Get "sass/main.scss" }} 
{{ $style := $sass | resources.ToCSS }}

<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ $style.Permalink }}">
```